# .animation is not a function

Tags: jquery

I'm using Drupal and jQuery says `.animation is not a function`. Why am I getting this error?

```
(function($){
    var cg_parent = "#block-views-content_gallery-cg_block";
    var cg_items = cg_parent + " ul";
    var cg_item = cg_items + " li";

    $(cg_item + ".views-row-first div.cg_item").addClass("active");
    $(cg_item + ".views-row-first div.cg_item").bind("mouseenter", function() {
        $("div.cg_item.active div.cg_body_content").animation({ left: '100px' }, 100, function() {
            alert("je;;p");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/seejee/sYFR9/7/

Comment: jQuery object has `animate` method not `animation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is named `animate` not `animation`:

```
$("div.cg_item.active div.cg_body_content").animate({ left:'100px' }, 100, function() {  
    alert("je;;p");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `animation` with `animate`, and this will do the work :)